# Composer installed, but get /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

Tags: php, centos, composer-php, centos7

On CentOS 7, I installed PHP 7.1.

Then I installed composer with:

```
cd /tmp
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php71     --> used php71 instead of php, php didn't work
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then, when using `composer`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory
```

When using `sudo composer`, I get:

```
sudo: composer: command not found
```

Comment: You could symlink `/usr/bin/php` to `/usr/bin/php71`. (Or wherever it is...)

Comment: Did you make the composer executable? `chmod a+x composer`

Comment: I ran this command and composer works now: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php71 /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As [@alexhowansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878731/composer-installed-but-get-usr-bin-env-php-no-such-file-or-directory/70213715#comment74792418_43878731), I ran the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php71 /usr/bin/php
```

Now the composer command works.

Comment: This help. Note: in Monterey, you need to alter the command to: sudo ls -s <existing php folder> /usr/local/bin/php, whereas <existing php folder> can be  /Applications/AMPPS/apps/php74/bin/php if you have AMPPS, etc...

Comment: sudo ln -s <existing php folder> /usr/local/bin/php

Fixed the command mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: This is still work for me, i install composer from their website and use it globally with this command 'sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer' but it didnt work, after that i use this command 'sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php' and its work, i use lampp btw, ThankYou

Answer (score 12):

You need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` variable. The easiest way is to throw it in your profile or bash_profile located at either:

- ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_profile

You would add the following to one of those files:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
```

For more details, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

If you are logged in when you add it, you can force Linux to read the file again and update the path (once the changes are made) by using `source` from the bash prompt:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

As for the `php7` vs. `php` issue, as Alex suggested, you can make a symlink so it works kinda like an alias.

Comment: One thing I'll add here: your mileage may vary per specific use case. When I added `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"` to my .bash_aliases, running `which php` returned `/usr/local/bin//php`. So, I modified it to `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"`, which works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me [Centos 7 with php 7.1] :
yum install php71w-cli

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the cli package.

`yum install php71u-cli` is what I needed to do for IUS php.

Answer (score -2):

This problem arises when you have composer installed locally.

To make it globally executable,run the below command in terminal,

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```